# Failed to install sshpass linux Ubuntu

Tags: sshpass

After `sudo apt-get update` I tried to install sshpass library with

```
sudo apt-get install sshpass
```

But I get this error message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 yate-alsa : Depends: yate-core (= 5.4.0-1-1ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I don't know what that `yate-core` is and why I get this error message. any idea ?

**[UPDATE]**

After I run `sudo apt-get install -f` I get this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gstreamer0.10-gconf gstreamer0.10-plugins-base gstreamer0.10-plugins-good gstreamer0.10-pulseaudio gstreamer0.10-x libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0 libgstreamer0.10-0
  libyate5.2.0 linux-headers-4.4.0-45 linux-headers-4.4.0-45-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-47 linux-headers-4.4.0-47-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-51
  linux-headers-4.4.0-51-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-53 linux-headers-4.4.0-53-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-57 linux-headers-4.4.0-57-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-59
  linux-headers-4.4.0-59-generic linux-image-4.2.0-42-generic linux-image-4.4.0-45-generic linux-image-4.4.0-47-generic linux-image-4.4.0-51-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-53-generic linux-image-4.4.0-57-generic linux-image-4.4.0-59-generic linux-image-extra-4.2.0-42-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-45-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-47-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-51-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-53-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-57-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-59-generic linux-signed-image-4.2.0-42-generic linux-signed-image-4.4.0-45-generic linux-signed-image-4.4.0-47-generic
  linux-signed-image-4.4.0-51-generic linux-signed-image-4.4.0-53-generic linux-signed-image-4.4.0-57-generic linux-signed-image-4.4.0-59-generic ubuntu-core-launcher
  yate-alsa yate-core
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  yate-core
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  yate-core
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 198 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/1,517 kB of archives.
After this operation, 5,920 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 443120 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../yate-core_5.4.0-1-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking yate-core (5.4.0-1-1ubuntu2) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/yate-core_5.4.0-1-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/etc/yate/ysipchan.conf', which is also in package yate 5.5.1-ubuntu1-sico2~xenial
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/yate-core_5.4.0-1-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Have you run `apt-get -f install` and tried again?

Comment: did you try to execute `sudo apt-get -f install` ?

Comment: please check my update . Thx :)

Comment: Is it ok if I remove this `/var/cache/apt/archives/yate-core_5.4.0-1-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb` ?

Comment: `sudo apt-get autoremove` fixed my problem. After this i managed to install sshpass.  Thx :)

Comment: What is the content of /etc/apt/sources.list and all the files in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ ? are you running a mix of Ubuntu versions ? Do you know how the packages "yate-alsa" or "yate" ended up in your system ? Did you install any packages manually lately using "dpkg -i" ?

Comment: please show `grep -P '^[ \t]*[^#[ \t]+' /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list`  and `apt-cache policy yate-core` edit your question for that.

Comment: I just wanted to point out that Ubuntu 18.04.1 has a problem installing sshpass because of a bug in their /etc/apt/sources.list which only has 4 entries. It can be fixed by following the directions here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1065093/different-sources-list-entries-between-18-04-server-and-18-04-1-server-isos I know this isn't your issue, but in case someone is having the same ansible issue I was having (sshpass is a dependency that can't get installed) this will point them in that direction because I found this post a few hours before I found the other solution.